# Symfony CollectionType with no entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have a:

```
class Q&A
{
    private $question
    private $answer
}
```

I need a collection (`CollectionType`) of `Q&A`s, but there is no inverse side entity in my model (`Q&A` entity has no **ManyToOne** relationship with any other entity).

**Question**

What are my options here ?

I also have:

```
class Page
{  
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Content")
     */
    private $contents;
}
```

I thought about making the `Page` class as `abstract` and create a separate entity for each page type, each inheriting from `Page`.

That way I could

```
class Q&APage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Q&A")
     */
    private $q&as;
}
```

But it's not a big website, I've got like 5 different page types on it, I feel it would be overkill to have a different entity for each page type.

Comment: Create a model class (eg. `AppBundle\Model\QACollection`) that can hold an array of `AppBundle\Entity\QA` and associate a form with that.

Comment: Thanks, I really shoud have thought of that before. It's working fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this has nothing to do with Symfony. This is a Doctrine thing. By the way, you have no overkill here, because your **Model** should make sense and be rational, to let you develop your codebase.

There exist so many situations in which, the programmer, designs a malformed Model, and gets into trouble, while goes through developing the codebase.

After all this, how do you know that:

> That is not a big website

? Many of today's big websites, have not been so big from the beginning. so it would be a good practice for you as a developer to try, not to trifle the **Model Design**.

The proposed design looks good, and to be honest, you have a good understanding of data structures needed for your model.

You need to have a:

```
class QuestionAndAnswer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="QuestionAndAnswerPage", inversedBy="questionAndAnswers")
     */
     private $questionAndAnswerPage;
}
```

and a:

```
class QuestionAndAnswerPage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuestionAndAnswer", mappedBy="questionAndAnswerPage")
     */
     private $questionAndAnswers;
}
```

Tip: Try to use complete english words and phrases all the time, as that is a best practice in object oriented world. Keep in mind that, your users don't need to read them. They are there for you to not get stuck in malformed phrases in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing my original post and for this answer!

Comment: Sorry, I sent the previous comment without finishing it and can't edit now.
What I mean with "it's not a big website" is that it won't ever get big, it's really a very small local workshop showcase website which has been that size for 10 years now, I'm just refreshing it. Nice to know my idea was a good one though.
I went with ccKep's suggestion before you answered and it works great, do you still think I need to switch to this model design ?

Also thanks for the tips on using complete words!

Comment: Metrics for a good Model Design, are out there on the Internet, but the whole idea of what to put in your model comes from the problem domain, you are going to solve. Entities and their NAMEs should really exist out there. for example If I were you, I'd not go with an entity named `Content`, because that does not make much sense. Almost everything is content. You should be more specific with entities in your model design process.